# opencv_gpu compilation problem

Tags: opencv, cuda

I use  to generate a vs solution file. When I try to  the project, the opencv_gpu project gives following error:

`error C3861: '': identifier not found 

error C3861: 'nppiCanny_32f8u_C1R': identifier not found 

error C2664: 'nppiSum_8u_C1R' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'Npp32s *' to 'Npp8u *' 

error C2664: 'nppiSum_8u_C4R' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'Npp32s *' to 'Npp8u *'`

I am using NPP3.2. Other projects seem  fine. Thank you.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=202406

Answer (score 1):

There's a discussion about this error here:

http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/

Apparently some of the users solved it.